# Fullcalendar-4 doesn't render events

Tags: json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm updating a working fullcalendar 2.9 implementation to version 4.1. My 4.1 code works to the point where it is supposed to render the JSON data into the calendar. It retrieves the JSON data but doesn't display it.

I've been reviewing the examples from fullcalendar.io but havent been able to find an answer

Here's the code from my development server (ColdFusion 2016, CommonSpot 10, IIS etc.)

This is here because my internal dev box isn't using an SSL cert.

```
<cfif CGI.HTTPS IS "off">
            <cfset variables.s = 0>
            <cfset variables.url="http://" & #CGI.SERVER_NAME# & "/customCF/schoologyCalendar/controller/schoologyCalendarController.cfc?method=ajaxPassThrough">
        <cfelse>
            <cfset variables.s = 1>
            cfset variables.url="https://" & #CGI.SERVER_NAME# & "/customCF/schoologyCalendar/controller/schoologyCalendarController.cfc?method=ajaxPassThrough">
        </cfif>
```

This is the calendar implementation

```
    <link href='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/core/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/bootstrap/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <script src='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/core/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/daygrid/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/bootstrap/main.min.js'></script>

    <script src='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/moment/moment.js'></script>
    <script src='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/moment-timezone/moment-timezone-with-data.js'></script>

    <script src='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/moment/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/ADF/thirdParty/jquery/fullcalendar/4.1.0/packages/moment-timezone/main.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var initialTimeZone = 'UTC';
        var loadingEl = document.getElementById('loading');
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('fullCalendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            plugins: ['bootstrap','dayGrid', 'moment', 'momentTimezone'],
            themeSystem:'bootstrap',
            timeZone: "#request.dodea.regiondata[1].values.timeZone#",
            header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth'
            },
            defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            selectable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: '#variables.url#',
                method: 'get',
                allDayDefault: false,
                startParam: 'start_date',
                endParam: 'end_date',
                extraParams:{
                    building_id: '#request.dodea.regiondata[1].values.schoology_id#',
                    state: #variables.s#
                }

            }

         });

      calendar.render();

    });
```

Here's an example of the JSON that my CFC returns from a webservice

```
{
    "event": [
        {
            "id": 1624074493,
            "title": "Int. Band to Music in the Parks",
            "description": "",
            "start": "2019-04-27 06:00:00",
            "has_end": 1,
            "end": "2019-04-27 21:30:00",
            "all_day": 0,
            "editable": 1,
            "rsvp": 0,
            "comments_enabled": 1,
            "type": "event",
            "realm": "school",
            "school_id": 102769929,
            "links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/api.schoology.com\/v1\/schools\/102769929\/events\/1624074493"
            }
        }
 ],
    "total": 56,
    "links": {
        "self": "http:\/\/api.schoology.com\/v1\/school\/102769929\/events?start_date=2019-04-28&start=0&limit=100"
    }
}
```

So all of this runs to the point where the JSON is returned from the CFC and calendar.render() fires, I get a nice calendar with no events.

I know I'm missing something but I can't put a finger on it.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FullCalendar expects the JSON returned by your event feed URL to contain a simple array of events, and nothing else. The problem you've got here is that you're returning a more complex object and the calendar code doesn't know where to look to get the event data within that.

Of the sample JSON you posted above, the only bit your server should be producing and returning to fullCalendar through that URL is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1624074493,
        "title": "Int. Band to Music in the Parks",
        "description": "",
        "start": "2019-04-27 06:00:00",
        "has_end": 1,
        "end": "2019-04-27 21:30:00",
        "all_day": 0,
        "editable": 1,
        "rsvp": 0,
        "comments_enabled": 1,
        "type": "event",
        "realm": "school",
        "school_id": 102769929,
        "links": {
            "self": "http:\/\/api.schoology.com\/v1\/schools\/102769929\/events\/1624074493"
        }
    }
]
```

The rest of it is superfluous, and also confusing to the calendar software.

---

If it's not possible to change what the API returns, then you'll have to transform the data when it reaches the browser. FullCalendar provides the [events as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) facility to take account of this kind of situation. The only slight downside is that you have to write your own AJAX code.

Replace your `events: { ...` section with something like this:

```
eventSources: [{
  events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    var url = new URL('#variables.url#');
    var params = { 
      "start_date": info.start.toISOString(),
      "end_date": info.end.toISOString(),
      "building_id": '#request.dodea.regiondata[1].values.schoology_id#',
      "state": #variables.s#
    };
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(params);

    fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      successCallback(data.event); //just return the inner event array to fullCalendar
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      failureCallback(error);
    });
  },
  allDayDefault: false
}]
```

Comment: unfortunately that's not possible as I'm pulling the data from another application's API and it's an all or nothing proposition

Comment: In that case you'll have to define a custom event source. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sending me down the right path. I've implemented the following events function and it's working.

I created this events function and it's working

```
events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback){
                        var url = '#variables.url#';
                        var completeURL = url + '&start_date=' + info.start + '&end_date=' + info.end + '&building_id=' + #request.dodea.regiondata[1].values.schoology_id# + '&state=' + #variables.s# + '&timezone=' + '#request.dodea.regiondata[1].values.timeZone#';

                        fetch(completeURL).then(function(response) {
                            return response.json();
                        })
                        .then(function(data) {
                            successCallback(data); 
                        })
                    },
```